# Function to generate the corresponding mask for a bit field

Tags: c, position, field, mask, bit

I have a 32 bit register R with various bit fields declared as follows:

```
typedef union {
  uint32_t raw;
  struct {
    uint32_t F1 : 0x4;
    uint32_t F2 : 0x8;
    uint32_t F3 : 0x8;
    uint32_t F4 : 0xC;
  }
} reg1
```

I also have a regWrite macro that read-modify-writes a field in the register as follows:

```
#define RegWrite(Reg, Field, Addr, Val) do {
  Reg.raw = read32(Addr);
  Reg.Field = Val;
  write32(Addr, Reg.raw);
} while(0)
```

Now, I wanted to enhance the RegWrite module to optionally output a script to console instead of actually programming hardware, so that this can be saved and re-run at a later point of time.

For example, if I call out to regWrite as follows:

```
regWrite(reg1, F2, 0x12345678, 0xC)
```

The print output from the macro should look something like this:

```
set variable1 [read 32 0x12345678]
set variable1 [ ($variable1 & 0xFFFFF00F) | (0xC << 4) ]
write 32 0x12345678 variable1
```

How would I generate 0xFFFFF00F, and 4 within the macro? Thanks!

Comment: Please show exactly how the "print out" should look like. I cannot imagine how a single macro can usefully do that. Would you like to do it as "Fmask(F1) ->0xf" and "Fpos(F1) -> 0x0" ? That is possible with just a little pre-processor magic. To put it differently, please show the code using the desired macro, assuming that it exists. I need some context of what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's not possible to implement a generic function or macro for what you need. For generic code you need to get both the offset and the size of each member in *bits*, which is impossible. What further complicates things is that the compiler is allowed to add padding between the members, and even rearrange the order.

Comment: *I need to create a C function/#define-macro that takes in the name of a field and prints out the corresponding bit mask, and start position.* This really sounds like an XY problem.  What issue are you really trying to solve? If you need a bit mask for portability reasons, you'd probably do better to drop bit fields entirely.  If you want bit masks so you know where your bits really are, again you need to drop using bit fields entirely.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated code to reflect my actual need. The register is a union, so I'm thinking the compiler cant pad stuff now? Cos I'd be defining fields for all 32 bits. And I'm having to use both bit fields and masks since they form two different worlds. The former, for my code, and the latter to generate a script running on a different environment. Both are non-flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question lacks some important information, including:

- What do you try to achive?
- Why do you need to give just the struct member name as an argument?

This might be an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Anyway, from the literal requirement:

> Fn(*X*) should **print** out 0x*Y*, and *Z*.

You can do this with a macro:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct F {
    uint32_t F1 : 0x4;
    uint32_t F2 : 0x8;
    uint32_t F3 : 0x8;
    uint32_t F4 : 0xC;
};

#define Fn(Fx) do {                    \
    union {                            \
        struct F f;                    \
        uint32_t u;                    \
    } v;                               \
    v.u = 0;                           \
    v.u = ~v.u;                        \
    v.f.Fx = 0;                        \
    uint32_t m = v.u;                  \
    int b;                             \
    for (b = 0; (v.u & 1) != 0; b++) { \
        v.u >>= 1;                     \
    }                                  \
    (void)printf("0x%0X %d\n", m, b);  \
} while (0)

int main(void) {
    /* Fn(F2) should print out 0xFFFFF00F, and 4. */
    Fn(F2);
    /* Fn(F3) should print out 0xFFF00FFF, and 12. */
    Fn(F3);

    return 0;
}
```

Some notes to this hacked "solution":

- It uses `do { ... } while(0)` to make sure that the macro can't be used as an expression, only as a statement.
- There is no interpretation of `Fx` until it is read by the compiler in the line `v.f.Fx = 0`.
- The code is only for C.
- Each time it is used it will take clock cycles, and it needs code space. This seems to be unnecessary for constant expressions.
- It works by defining a union that can be used as the struct or the resulting `uint32_t`.
- The mask is generated by setting all bits to 1, and then resetting only the given struct member to 0.
- The bit offset is obtained by looking for the first 0-bit from the right.

Please be aware that the standard makes **no promisses** about the order of bitfields in a memory word ("unit"), not even that they are in the same memory word. For further details see the chapter "Structure and union specifiers" of the version of the standard your compiler complies to.

But if you need the values for other purposes you should think about your architectur, and of course of the possibilities of the C standard. As I said, presumably you're trying to solve a completely other problem. And for this, the shown source is **not the solution**.

Comment: Neat trick, but not really something that could be used in performance sensitive code. Or translated to C++. And it is very obscure and convoluted, so please try to add some comments to explain what's happening and why you do what you do (you want to help visitors to learn something, not just copy-paste without understanding and promote cargo cult programming).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found some time to search for some more usable solution.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct F {
    uint32_t F1 : 0x4;
    uint32_t F2 : 0x8;
    uint32_t F3 : 0x8;
    uint32_t F4 : 0xC;
};

typedef union {
    struct F f;
    uint32_t u;
} Fn_type;

uint32_t Fn_mask_helper(Fn_type v) {
    return ~v.u;
}

#define Fn_mask(Fx) Fn_mask_helper((Fn_type){.u=0, .f.Fx=~0})

int Fn_bit_offset_helper(Fn_type v) {
    v.u = ~v.u;
    int b;
    for (b = 0; (v.u & 1) != 0; b++) {
        v.u >>= 1;
    }
    return b;
}

#define Fn_bit_offset(Fx) Fn_bit_offset_helper((Fn_type){.u=0, .f.Fx=~0})

int main(void) {
    uint32_t m2 = Fn_mask(F2);
    int b2 = Fn_bit_offset(F2);
    (void)printf("0x%0X %d\n", m2, b2);
    uint32_t m3 = Fn_mask(F3);
    int b3 = Fn_bit_offset(F3);
    (void)printf("0x%0X %d\n", m3, b3);

    return 0;
}
```

To access the field (struct member) specified in the argument we need to use a macro. In C we can't use the name of a struct member as an argument on its own. *Remember, the C preprocessor knows nothing about C. It is a quite simple search'n'replace tool.*

This macro expands to the call to its helper function which takes the union as a parameter. The macro replacement text contains an initialization for this union with all bits on 0 but the bits of the concerned struct member.

The helper functions do the same as the macro in my other answer. In `Fn_bit_offset_helper()` the inversion of `v.u` together with the right shift ensures that the loop will not loop forever.

*Note: You need a compiler in compliance with at least C99.*

Comment: And now I'm quite curious about some solution that creates constants right at compile time! ;-)

Comment: Ah no. I lost interest in providing one, because of the total lack of feedback from OP.